# How to store std::atomic in a structure as a value in std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, stdatomic

The `std::atomic` is totally fine to be stored as a value in `std::unordered_map` regardless of the question "what it means to allow a copy of atomic", it even can be stored in `std::pair` in the value.

But when it comes to store a structure which contains `std::atomic` the compiler comes with hard to understand error messages.

**The code**

Here is the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7f97b64cf)

```
#include <atomic>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

struct LexemData {
    unsigned int id{};
    std::atomic<size_t> counter{};
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::atomic<size_t>> dict1;

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::pair<unsigned int, std::atomic<size_t>>> dict2;

std::unordered_map<std::string, LexemData> dict3;


int main()
{
    std::string lexem("lexem");
    
    dict2.insert({ lexem, std::make_pair(0, 0) });

    dict2.insert({ lexem, {0, 0} }); // This doesn't compile (1)

    dict3.insert({ lexem, LexemData {0,0} });  // This doesn't compile (2)
}
```

What makes both cases above so different from pure `std::atomic` storage and storing through `std::make_pair` that:

1. inserting with initialization list doesn't work
2. inserting of the structure object doesn't work

I guess the question "what it means to allow a copy of atomic" can be equally addressed to all approaches here.

What can be done to make them working?

I am especially interested in the second case, I feel that I miss some kind of operator or way to return a reference instead of object to be provided, but I can't see it.

The error messages are too verbose to be put here; if somebody knows how to do it, please edit the question so that I could learn.

Comment: That's what [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) is for. Note that emplace is less efficient than insert if the element is already in the map, since it always has to allocate a new node, even if it has to destroy it afterwards when it finds a duplicate. But in cases like this, where you have non-moveable types, it's your only option. And if an insert truly takes place, it is the most efficient option

Comment: You can use a `emplace` with `std::piecewise_construct` when you need construct an element in-place with no copy or move of the element whatsoever. https://godbolt.org/z/dzrGo4hva

Comment: @Homer512, thank you so much for the clue! Regarding efficiency, wouldn't [`try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace) solve this problem?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, thank you so much for both pinpoints. Would it be different from `dict3.try_emplace(lexem,0,0);` in terms of construction [godbolt.org/z/7W3eqbKn7](https://godbolt.org/z/7W3eqbKn7)? I see it is much better if the element is already exist, but I am in two minds if in C++17 implementation it covers the construction issues, as well.

Comment: You're right, `try_emplace` solves the issue. Forgot about that