# Is there a way to store std::atomic in a structure as a value in MS Concurrency::concurrent_unordered_map?

Tags: c++, std

The MS [Concurrency::concurrent_unordered_map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/reference/concurrent-unordered-map-class?view=msvc-170) doesn't provide the `emplace` method, so I don't have a chance to use advice from [How to store std::atomic in a structure as a value in std::unordered_map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77981797/how-to-store-stdatomic-in-a-structure-as-a-value-in-stdunordered-map).

Is there a chance to get this [code](https://godbolt.org/z/bzc37jjYd) compilable?

```
#include <atomic>
#include <string>
#include <concurrent_unordered_map.h>

struct LexemData {
    unsigned int id{};
    std::atomic<size_t> counter{};
};

int main()
{
    Concurrency::concurrent_unordered_map<std::string, LexemData> dict;

    std::string lexem("lexem");
    
    dict.insert({ lexem, LexemData {0,0} });  // Doesn't compile
}
```

It doesn't compile with the error message (more is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bzc37jjYd)):

```
<source>(16): error C2665: 'Concurrency::concurrent_unordered_map<std::string,LexemData,std::hash<_Key_type>,std::equal_to<_Key_type>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Key_type,_Element_type>>>::insert': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types with 
[
    _Key_type=std::string,
    _Element_type=LexemData
]
```

The reason is quite simple, the LexemData can't be copied because it contains `std::atomic` and map's value must be constructed `emplace`.

I need to increment this counter from many threads.

Another option would be using [oneapi::tbb::concurrent_unordered_map](https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/latest/elements/oneTBB/source/containers/concurrent_unordered_map_cls.html) which provides `emplace` and would be portable, but I am not ready to add another library if there is a chance to solve this with existing container from MS.

Comment: **Doesn't compile** The [mcve] requirement: *"It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. <...> Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it.*

Comment: @273K, the line of code is commented in the code. I've added some explanation on the reason of the error. I don't see a way to copy [this](https://godbolt.org/z/bzc37jjYd) error log here effectively. Could you please show me a way to edit the message to paste this verbose error message here?

Comment: In this case you want the error. The notes that follow are useful supplementary information that I'd be ok with if you linked.

Comment: @user4581301, I lost you. What you mean to be linked? What you mean with "you want the error"? Do you mean the text of error? Compiler gives very verbose diagnostic, how to put it here or link? Can you please edit the post and show the way?

Comment: Surprised no upvotes.  Apart from one quibble (which I agree with) it is well written and highly pertinent.

Comment: Of the zounds-long error message you only need to put the first part into the question. `<source>(16): error C2665: 'Concurrency::concurrent_unordered_map<std::string,LexemData,std::hash<_Key_type>,std::equal_to<_Key_type>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Key_type,_Element_type>>>::insert': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types with [ _Key_type=std::string, _Element_type=LexemData ]`. The remainder is notes letting you know all the alternatives it tried. Nice to have, but not necessary. Put the error into the question, and if you feel like it, link the whole thing.

Comment: ... which you can do by putting the code into your favourite online compiler and then linking to that (as you surely already know)

Comment: @user4581301, thank you, will follow. Is it better now? BTW, the link to the code was provided from the very beginning, so everybody was able to open and see. Anyway, agree.

Comment: @PaulSanders, isn't it what was done initially when I posted the link to the [code](https://godbolt.org/z/bzc37jjYd) just above the source code? That's exactly the reason I was surprised with the requests to provide such a verbose diagnostic. But I agree here with *user4581301*, the first line is good to be copied to see at once.

Comment: For this message I'd reproduce the everything down to the closing square bracket because it supplies the types the compiler's looking for.

Comment: @user4581301, agree. Added, but still not sure if it is possible to format it better, keeping new lines in the quote string.

Comment: I'd use a pre-formatted block with no assigned language: `\`\`\`none` before and `\`\`\`` after.

Comment: _isn't it what was done initially_ So it was!  Apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should implement the following constructors on your struct.
The main thing is atomics are not moveable so you need to copy

Demo : https://godbolt.org/z/hh65aE1TY

```
#include <atomic>
#include <string>
#include <concurrent_unordered_map.h>

struct LexemData final
{
    LexemData(unsigned int i, std::size_t count) :
        id{i},
        counter{count}
    {
    }

    LexemData(const LexemData& rhs) :
        id { rhs.id },
        counter {rhs.counter.load() }
    {
    }

    LexemData& operator=(const LexemData& rhs)
    {
        if ( &rhs != this)
        {
            id = rhs.id;
            counter = rhs.counter.load();
        }
    }

    LexemData(LexemData&&) = delete;  // atomic is not moveable
    LexemData& operator=(LexemData&&) = delete;

    ~LexemData() = default;

    unsigned int id;
    std::atomic<std::size_t> counter;
}; 

int main()
{
    Concurrency::concurrent_unordered_map<std::string, LexemData> dict;
    dict.insert({"lexem",{0u,0}});
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One question, what is the context the assignment operator is supposed to be used? I set the breakpoint (in a real code which increases, reads, etc., not only where I add the item) and never got the code executed; even when I send the `counter` to output.

Comment: It is probably not needed for your code but it is a rule to implement both constructors or none.  Read this : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three